# CKAN Resource URL value

Tags: ckan

I’m using FIWARE CKAN for an application dealing with Digital Urban Services.

In this application, we need to integrate Orion and Cygnus_ngsi with CKAN and for this scope, we have configured in Cygnus the CKAN sink as following:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.type =   com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = ba753aae-7c1f-XXXX-XXXXX-cf893100ab53
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = ckan host
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = 8080
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.orion_url = http://orion ip:1026
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_persistence = row
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 30
```

After creating a subscription in Orion, performing an update context, the context data are stored in CKAN but the CKAN resource URL is not valued. The URL is needed for downloading the just created resource. 
Could you please tell me which value should have the URL in my scenario, where the data comes from Orion?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKAN Resource URL empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101219/ckan-resource-url-empty)